# Android studio Selenium WebDriver does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use selenium in my java code. But I'm facing webdriver issue

For

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I am getting this error

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe`

So I added it my system environmental variables. I tried adding the location to the path both will .exe and without it and restarted but no luck.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I noticed that "/" is getting added to the location I add. When I checked

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

I am getting just Working Directory = /

For some reason, '/' is automaticcally getting added to the path.

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something very weird. You will not be able to use 32-bit ChromeDriver for Windows with Android device, it comes with [Appium](http://appium.io) installation via [appium-chromedriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-chromedriver) package.

Just make sure that [chromedriver version matches your Chrome version on the Android device](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/) and you should be good to go.

The essential Chrome browser initialization code would be something like:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
dc.setBrowserName(MobileBrowserType.CHROME);
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
driver.get("https://example.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Check out [Appium - Code Examples - Java - Chrome on Android Test using Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for more information and example project.